# Shorted 12V wire to GND in ATX power supply. Did I fry it?

Tags: power-supply

I'm a total noob, please forgive me.

I have several components that require 12V DC, and I decided to use an old computer power supply to give me the juice. 
I snipped and stripped a matching pair of yellow and black wires... 
After marveling at the results of hotwiring the electronic lock, I decided to test out the EL wire I bought ages ago.
However, I could not resist touching the wires together to see what a 12V spark looks like and now the power supply's fan stopped. 
I tested the outlet, and it's fine. Did I just fry my power supply? Or perhaps I blew a fuse in the thing?

Why did my PS stop working and how might I fix it?

Comment: Some PSUs have output short protection, some don't. Some would have survived, others wouldn't.

Comment: Acceptable answer. But why would running the 12v feed directly into the ground fry the whole unit? Paired ground isn't designed to take an unused supply?

Comment: Thank you @WesleyLee for the edits. Like I said, I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm still learning. I actually started to say "Short circuited" but - I don't know any better. Thank you, sincerely.

Comment: There's really no way to tell just from the info in the question. I've accidentally shorted some PSUs before and most of them have survived. It really will depend on the model. If it doesn't turn back on again then obviously something is damaged inside, possibly a fuse, but it could also be one of the output devices, in which case it'll be much harder to repair..

Comment: Ok, then what else can I tell you? This PSU is an Austin DR-B300ATX - it came out of an old, junk computer and has been sitting on a shelf for a couple of years. It stopped working the second I crossed the wires. When you say "Survived" do you mean you managed to fix them? Or they simply kept ticking?
Your comments make for a good answer. "Yes" I fried it - "because" it's a cheap, old PSU

Comment: When I say "survived" I mean that most of the times when PSUs with output protection are shorted, they turn off, you power cycle it (remove its power input/disconnect the it from the outlet), and they will turn back on again if the fault condition was removed. I looked up this unit on google and apparently its a *very* cheap PSU, some buyers even received it with some parts of the wiring missing apparently.

Comment: I'd tell you to check the fuse but I think the energy in the PSUs capacitors would be enough to blow a component inside of it. Anyway, this questions is a bit close to be off-topic. Take a look at [this](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic) thread on meta and try to re-format it to avoid having it closed.

Comment: I thought flipping the switch on and off would be enough to power-cycle it, but it wasn't! Thing is working. Paste your comments as an answer, and I'll happily accept it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, and I'll be happy to edit whatever you paste to make it suitable reading for others. And no hurry. Can't accept for 24 hours, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting comments as an answer, since apparently it helped OP solve his problem.*

Some PSUs have output short protection, some don't. Some would have survived, others wouldn't.

There's really no way to tell just from the info in the question. I've accidentally shorted some PSUs before and most of them have survived. It really will depend on the model. If it doesn't turn back on again then obviously something is damaged inside, possibly a fuse, but it could also be one of the output devices, in which case it'll be much harder to repair.

When I say "survived" I mean that **most of the times when PSUs with output protection are shorted, they turn off, you power cycle it (remove its power input/disconnect the it from the outlet), and they will turn back on again if the fault condition was removed**. I looked up this unit on google and apparently its a very cheap PSU, some buyers even received it with some parts of the wiring missing apparently.

I'd tell you to check the fuse but I think the energy in the PSUs capacitors would be enough to blow a component inside of it.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm an idiot and I should've tried that. (TBH, I thought that was the first thing I tried...Oh well!)